# HTML code of table with various row and column size

Tags: html

[image: table]

It seems easy but can't write the HTML code of the above table.
Here is what I tried so far:

```
  <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;" width="25%">
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Post what you have written so far

Comment: Hi Babar, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please post the HTML you tried so far? It will help us, help you debug the issue.

Comment: you can use [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) and [rowspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) attributes of `<td></td>` to achieve this.

Comment: i just tried wrote some code but it do not give me correct output

Comment: rowspan and colspan i used but do not giving correct results.can somebody give code of this?

Comment: attach the code here, so others can help you fix it

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png">
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;" width="25%">
<tr>
<td>col1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>

<table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I'm editing your answer for readability, including that above snippet and assuming that your last "table" tag is a closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you want html??

```
    <table align="center" width="590" height="590" >
  <tr>
    <td align="center" height="80" colspan="4">central text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" height="80" colspan="2">col</td>
    <td align="center" colspan="2">col</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" height="40">t</td>
    <td align="center" height="40">t</td>
    <td align="center" height="80" rowspan="2">t</td>
    <td align="center" rowspan="2">t</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" height="40">t</td>
    <td align="center" height="40">t</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" height="30">t</td>
    <td align="center" >t</td>
    <td align="center" >t</td>
    <td align="center" >t</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Like this?

Answer (score 1):

[colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) and [rowspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) was missing from your code.

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan=4 align="center">central text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 align="center">col(1)</td>
    <td colspan=2 align="center">col(2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td rowspan=2 align="center">text</td>
    <td rowspan=2 align="center">text</td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
    <td align="center">text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @BabarJunaid if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this though.

Comment: @BabarJunaid The check-mark is next to the answer, underneath the arrows with the Answer's vote count.

Comment: when color of check become green then its mean its correct answer?

Comment: thanx for guiding me.m new here.i did not know how to use stackoverflow

Comment: @BabarJunaid You're welcome. Stack Overflow can be confusing at first but once you get the hang of it, it is a great resource. Check out the tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour It is a great resource for those who are new here.

Comment: thanx.its my firtst question to stackoverflow and i appreciate people which give me answer and they give me correct answer in a little time.now m satisfy with stackoverflow